# Effectively getting time unit with Joda

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am looking for a neat solution to get the time units in Java 7 ( or using Joda date time)

Like, to 65 minutes, it should say 1 hour 5 minutes

To 30 minutes, it should just say 30 minutes

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you will have to do this conversion yourself. The jodatime classes usually have a `getMinutes()` method. That will give you 65 in your first example. You'll have to divide it by 60 and then move down a time unit with the remainder.

Comment: What are your input units? Always minutes, as in your example?

Comment: Yes, the input will always be minutes.

Comment: This question has been answered many times already on Stackoverflow, with example code for Joda-Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, use `org.joda.time.Period`.

For example, a general purpose solution might be to have a method that takes the number of milliseconds and returns a String of the form:

X hours, X minutes, X seconds, X milliseconds

```
public class DateTimeUtils {
  public static String toNicePeriodValue(Period period) {
    return period.getHours() + "hours " +
           period.getMinutes() + "minutes " +
           period.getSeconds() + "seconds " +
           period.getMillis() + "milliseconds";
  }
}
```

An easy way to create a Period object is like this:

```
public String nicePeriodValueFromMillis(long timeInMillis) {
  Period period = new Period(timeInMillis);
  String ret = DateTimeUtils.toNicePeriodValue(period);
  return ret;
}
```

And invoke it like this:

```
long timeInMillis = /* obtain somehow */
String nicePeriodValue = nicePeriodValue(timeInMillis);
System.out.println("Nice Period Value: " + nicePeriodValue);
```

This is not, of course, a complete solution, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `joda` time's [`normalizedStandard`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard%28%29) to print your output too.

Per the doc,

> Normalizes this period using standard rules, assuming a 12 month year,
>   7 day week, 24 hour day, 60 minute hour and 60 second minute.

An example for 65 minutes would be:

```
System.out.println(PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(Period.hours(0).plusMinutes(65).plusSeconds(0).normalizedStandard()));
```

Output:

```
1 hour and 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always minutes use the modulus operator `% 60` to find remaining minutes and `/ 60` to find hours.